# How to delete table certain table row created from dynamic dataTables using jquery?

Tags: jquery, dynamic, datatables, html-table

I have this code where when the user clicks the checkbox in the datables it will append certain lines in ANOTHER TABLE

```
    $('#warehouseT tbody').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function (e) {
                    var check = this.checked;
                    console.log(check);
                    if (check === true) {
                        document.getElementById("order").style.visibility = 'visible';
                    var productName = $(this).closest("tr").find(".productName").text();
                    var color = $(this).closest("tr").find(".color").text();
                    var size = $(this).closest("tr").find(".size").text();
                    var Qty = $(this).closest("tr").find(".Qty").text();
                    $('#data').append('<tr>\n\
                                      <td><input type="text" name="productName" value="' + productName + '"/></td>\n\
                                      <td><input type="text" name="" value="' + color + '"/></td>\n\
                                      <td><input type="text" name="" value="' + size + '"/></td>\n\\n\
                                      <td><input type="text" name="" value="' + Qty + '"/></td>\n\\n\
                                      <td><input type="number" name="" value="0"/></td>\n\
                                    </tr>');}else{
//missing codes
}
                });
```

currently it is working. It is appending lines to the ANOTHER table

```
<div id="order" style=" width:60%; visibility: hidden">
                <h2>Replenishment Request</h2><br/>
                <table id="data" class="table table-bordered" >
                    <thead>
                        <tr>

                            <th>Product Name</th>
                            <th>Color</th>
                            <th>Size</th>
                            <th>Current Quantity</th>
                            <th>Quantity To Be send (?)</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="info">

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

The problem is when the user clicks the checkbox again, it should delete the line in the ANOTHER TABLE.

The dataTables with checkbox
[image]

The ANOTHER TABLE
[image]

Comment: Please show you append code

Comment: @void i added the my append codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed your if/else like:

```
var index;
if (check === true) {
    document.getElementById("order").style.visibility = 'visible';
    index = $(this).closest("tr").index();
    var productName = $(this).closest("tr").find(".productName").text();
    var color = $(this).closest("tr").find(".color").text();
    var size = $(this).closest("tr").find(".size").text();
    var Qty = $(this).closest("tr").find(".Qty").text();
    $('#data').append('<tr id="rowNum'+index+'">\n\
                                      <td><input type="text" name="productName" value="' + productName + '"/></td>\n\
                                      <td><input type="text" name="" value="' + color + '"/></td>\n\
                                      <td><input type="text" name="" value="' + size + '"/></td>\n\\n\
                                      <td><input type="text" name="" value="' + Qty + '"/></td>\n\\n\
                                      <td><input type="number" name="" value="0"/></td>\n\
                                    </tr>');
} else {
    $("#rowNum"+index).remove();
}
```

I am making every appended row unique by alloting it a unique id. Then you can play with it!

Comment: thank you the idea works, i change the codes above to make it work with mine. :)) will be posting the whole solution on another comment :)) thank youuuu

Comment: the only problem is  'var index = $(this).closest("tr").index();' is not called as a global variable..

Comment: i move the whole `var index = $(this).closest("tr").index();` line outside the if statement to make it work :)) thank you again :))

Comment: Yes thats inact better.. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use classes and ids to your advantage. you can also use `.clone()` to append the rows and navigate through the DOM tree with `.closest()` and `.find()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
        var newClass = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
     if ($(this).is(':checked')) {            
         var newItem = $(this).closest('tr').clone(true).attr('id', '').addClass(newClass);
            newItem.find('td:first').remove();
            $('.table2').append(newItem);
        }
        else {
         $('.table2').find('.' + newClass).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

```css
td {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
table {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tablesDiv">
    <table class="table1">
        <tr>
            <td>checked</td>
            <td>column 1</td>
            <td>column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row1">
            <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td>something 1</td>
            <td>something else 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row2">
            <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td>something 2</td>
            <td>something else 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row3">
            <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td>something 3</td>
            <td>something else 3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table class="table2">
        <tr>
            <td>column 1</td>
            <td>column 2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited the codes given by @void

```
$('#warehouseT tbody').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function (e) {
                    var check = this.checked;
                    console.log(check);
                    var index = $(this).closest("tr").index();
                    if (check === true) {
                        document.getElementById("order").style.visibility = 'visible';
                        var productName = $(this).closest("tr").find(".productName").text();
                        var color = $(this).closest("tr").find(".color").text();
                        var size = $(this).closest("tr").find(".size").text();
                        var Qty = $(this).closest("tr").find(".Qty").text();
                        $('#data').append('<tr id="rowNum'+index+'">\n\
                                      <td><input type="text" name="productName" value="' + productName + '"/></td>\n\
                                      <td><input type="text" name="" value="' + color + '"/></td>\n\
                                      <td><input type="text" name="" value="' + size + '"/></td>\n\\n\
                                      <td><input type="text" name="" value="' + Qty + '"/></td>\n\\n\
                                      <td><input type="number" name="" value="0"/></td>\n\
                                    </tr>');
                    } else {
                     //   var index =   document.getElementById($('#data').find('[id="rowNum\\[\\]"]')).value;
                        //var index = $('#data').closest("tr").index();
                        $('#data').find("#rowNum" + index).remove();
                        console.log("#rowNum" + index);
                    }
                });
```